# jQuery how to access JavaScript variable

Tags: jquery

I know this is a very simple (rather stupid) quesiton

I have a javascript array `chart["Ref"]` how would access it in Jquery

can you access javascript variables from jquery and vice versa.

Yes I know jquery is JavaScript still ;-)

Comment: You just access it by its name. The main question is in which scope it is. You'd have to post some more code so we could see where the variable is in context.

Comment: If you know jQuery is Javascript, *why* do you think variable access would be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to do with the array??

you could loop it with:

```
 $.each(chart, function() { 
    //your code here, you could access to the current element with "this"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You access it normally. jQuery is still JavaScript, fancy JavaScript, but JavaScript. You can access any and all variables normally within jQuery.

Of course, variable scope rules apply here.

Answer (score 0):

Just access it normally.

```
chart["Ref"]
```

It's still only javascript

Answer (score 0):

If scope allows you can access any variable on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question. `jQuery *is* Javascript.` So yes, you can access other non-jQuery object variables (provided the variable is in scope, as others have pointed out).

If you'd like to call jQuery functions on your array (like `each`, for example) you can do that as well:

```
$(chart).each(function(idx, obj) {
    // do stuff
});
```